Finding $\left[\left(\frac{A^3-B^3}{B^3}\right)+\left(\frac{A^4+B^4}{B^4}\right)\right]$
Question: If $A=\displaystyle\int_0^1\left(1-x^{2023}\right)^{\frac 1{2022}}\, dx$ $\quad$and $\quad$$B=\displaystyle\int_0^1\left(1-x^{2022}\right)^{\frac 1{2023}}\, dx \quad$ then find the value of $\left[\left(\dfrac{A^3-B^3}{B^3}\right)+\left(\dfrac{A^4+B^4}{B^4}\right)\right]$

My attempt
Requierd to find $\dfrac{A^3}{B^3}+\dfrac{A^4}{B^4}$ so I am thinking about to use Intgration By Parts to generate this type of reation $A=kB\; ; k\in R$
Let $I(m,n)=\displaystyle\int_0^1\left(1-x^m\right)^{n}$ by IBP I get the reduction formula,
$$(1+mn)I(m,n)= \require{cancel}\cancelto{0}{x\big(1-x^m\big)^n\bigg\vert_0^1}+mn\,I(m,n-1)$$ $$
\left(1+\dfrac{2023}{2022}\right)A=\dfrac{2023}{2022}\int_0^1\big(1-x^{2023}\big)^{-\frac{2021}{2022}}\tag{1}$$
$$\left(1+\dfrac{2022}{2023}\right)B=\dfrac{2022}{2023}\int_0^1\left(1-x^{2022}\right)^{-\frac {2022}{2023}}\tag{2}$$
but in both $(1)$ and $(2)$ I could not transform $RHS$ in in terms of $B$, $A$  and got stuck, Please help.

Consider the implicit function
$$x^m + y^n = 1, \quad x, y \ge 0, \quad m, n > 0. \tag{1}$$
Clearly, $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ always satisfy $(1)$.  When $x \in [0,1]$, then $y = (1-x^m)^{1/n} \in [0,1]$, and vice versa.  So
$$A = \int_{x=0}^1 (1-x^{2023})^{1/2022} \, dx$$
is the area bounded by $x \ge 0$, $y \ge 0$, and $(1)$ for the choice $m = 2023$, $n = 2022$.  Similarly, $B$ is the area bounded by $x \ge 0$, $y \ge 0$, and $(1)$ for the choice $m = 2022$, $n = 2023$.  But these are the same, because $(1)$ is symmetric with respect to $m, n$.  So the first term $A^3 - B^3 = 0$, and the second term is simply
$$\frac{A^4 + B^4}{B^4} = 2.$$
